# Lenovo v570 ubuntu 12.04 wireless hard blocked even when ext. switch is on

Tags: wireless

JUST TO LET EVERYONE KNOW, I'VE SOLVED THIS. Some how it got turned off in Backtrack 5 and I was able to use the keyboard commands in bt5 to turn the wireless on.

When I run

```
iwconfig
```

it say's `lo` and `eth0` have no wireless extensions, but `wlan0` it says

```
IEEE 802.11bgn   ESSID:off/any
Mode:Managed   Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off
Retry  long limit:7   RTS the:off   Fragment the:off
Power Management:off
```

and I believe that's my problem, I just don't know how to turn it back on

Any help?

When I ran

```
lspci | grep Network
```

it gave me this

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intell Corporation Centrino Wireless -N + 
WiMAX 6150 (rev 67)
```

How I know that my wireless is hard blocked because when I run

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

I get

```
0: Ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

when I run

```
lshw -c network
```

I get.

```
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: mon1
   version: 67
   serial: 40:25:c2:d2:96:2c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list logical wireless ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-32-generic-pae firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:43 memory:d0500000-d0501fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: f0:de:f1:d7:a0:4d
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.0.65 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
```

another thing I've noticed is that I can't take my computer out of airplane mode. When I click on Dash>Network 
it tells me that Airplane mode is on and I when I flip it over to off, it says it's off, but I can't turn wireless on, and when I close and reopen the network window it is back on.

---

@belacqua

yeah when I do that, it turns this

```
0: Ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

into this

```
0: Ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
```

the exterior wireless switch turns it to this

```
0: Ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: What is the result of `lspci | grep Network`? (edit it into your question please). And it looks to me that you did not set a `essid` for your network(I can not see any reason that says it is locked due to hardware).

Comment: I don't know about that laptop, but some have a keyboard combination that also turns off wireless.  Check that if you haven't ruled it out.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be the problem:

```
ESSID:off/any
```

If so ... this will stop network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

and this will (manually) add the ESSID to wlan (change $id to your wireless network name):

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid $id
sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

It should result in you getting an IP address.

Comment: I tried what you said and it just resulted in a bunch of send_packets to  255.255.255.255 port 67 failing because the Network is down.